# Polars: Count number of rows where two or more columns are null

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I'd like to find the percentage of rows where two specific columns are both null or both populated.

I'd like to accomplish something similar to this SQL:

```
SELECT
     Field_A
     ,COUNT(*) as Row_Count
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN FIELD_B IS NULL AND FIELD_C IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Both_Null_Count
```

I tried this:

```
df_all_cols = df_all_cols.groupby(by=lineage_fields)\
    .agg([
        pl.count().alias('Row_Count'),
        (pl.col('TRACKING').is_null() & pl.col('ORDER NUMBER').is_null()).count().alias('Null_Order_And_Tracking'),
        (pl.col('TRACKING').is_not_null() & pl.col('ORDER NUMBER').is_not_null()).count().alias('NotNull_Order_And_Tracking')
])
```

However, all three columns return the same output for each row.

How can I do this with Polars?

Comment: A runnable example would help. It looks like maybe the issue is you're using `.count()` instead of `.sum()` - `.count()` doesn't count just the true values.

Comment: Thanks. It was as simple as replacing count with sum.